# How to display the output that Microsoft Graph API returns

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

In running the graph API that is given as sample: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/, it returns an output in the screen 
What info is it returning and how can I use it in a user interface....

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see what info is returned and try out different calls is to use the Graph Explorer at https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer.

Otherwise, check the documentation at https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs.

Answer (score 0):

That API endpoint (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/) return the user profile.

Here is the detail: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get

You can use the information however you wish on your client (e.g., display list of current licenses, display user information for confirmation and updates, etc.). Other user-related methods are here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user